# Merge Primary Keys - Cascade Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, cascade

Is there a way to merge two primary keys into one and then cascade update all affected relationships?  Here's the scenario:

Customers (idCustomer int PK, Company varchar(50), etc)

CustomerContacts (idCustomerContact int PK, idCustomer int FK, Name varchar(50), etc)

CustomerNotes (idCustomerNote int PK, idCustomer int FK, Note Text, etc)

Sometimes customers need to be merged into one.  For example, you have a customer with the id of 1 and another with the id of 2.  You want to merge both, so that everything that was 2 is now 1.  I know I could write a script that updates all affected tables one by one, but I'd like to make it more future proof by using the cascade rules, so I don't have to update the script every time there is a new relationship added.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really mean merge? It seems that you mean "replace". Because you can't have for example 2 rows in customer with the same ID.

Comment: Well I'd like for one customer to retain their id while another one assume that id. I guess it could be also referred to as a replace, I'm just using merge in the sense that two customers are being merged into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no automatic way to do it, but you have a couple options, you can manually write the procedures, or you can either code generate the merge on a regular basis or dynamically generate it at run-time.  To do this, you can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` to build the procedure dynamically.

You can also simply wrap the entire operation in a transaction (a good idea anyway).  The last step will be to remove the customer being merged out of, so if there is RI on a table you never added and you try to do a merge, it will fail because you cannot remove the customer being merged out of since there are dependent records in a table which wasn't already added to the merge procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Any more recent solution to this?

I have kind of the same problem and at the moment building the procedures dynamically seems too complicated. Here's how it could work in theory, but I guess it doesn't?

In one transaction:
1) Temporarily disable primary key constraint on Customers
2) Update Primary ID of Cingular to '1' which has a relationship update cascade rule taking care of the children 
3) Use a secondary key field to delete (only) Cingular
4) Enable primary key constraint on Customers

Looking forward to something like this in future T-SQL:

DELETE WITH UPDATE idCustomer = 1 FROM Customers WHERE idCustomer = 2;

;-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Triggers instead. On update of the Customers (idCustomer column), you do whatever needed modifications (Delete, Update ...) on the related tables.

Comment: Whether I use triggers or cascade update to update the affected tables, I still have no way of doing a merge as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will end up with two records for each of these tables that both have the same primary key.  Is this your intention?

```
        Customers
    idCustomer Company
         1     AT&T
         2     Cingular
```

After the merge will become

```
        Customers
    idCustomer Company
         1     AT&T
         1     Cingular
```

In any case, the most future proof solution would be to write a procedure.  You could pass the procedure both customers and it would do all the work of updating all the tables as necessary.